# OpenShift Kafka brokers taking a long time to reboot

Tags: apache-kafka, openshift

We have a Kafka cluster on OpenShift and a restart of a broker is taking quite a long time (~10 mins). We tried increasing the number of brokers from 8 to 10 as well as increasing the memory per broker by ~50%, but without a noticeable impact. After the update we have roughly 4800 partitions per broker. While this is still above the recommended 4000 partitions per broker, we were still expecting at least some reduction in restart time.

What else could be causing the slow restart time?